# Convert CSV with Headers to JSON with GeoLocation

Tags: python, json, csv, geolocation

I have a CSV with the first row as the headers:

```
location_id name latitude longitude
```

I have then 10k rows of data. Latitude and Longitude are numbers

I need my output to look like that:

```
[
  {
    "location_id":"foo",
    "name":"bar",
    "latitude":28.55323,
    "longitude":-81.28482,
    "geo":{
        "__type": "GeoPoint",
        "latitude": 28.55323,
        "longitude": -81.28482
    }
  },
....
]
```

How can I do that in Python by writing a script? I'm using Python for Windows

Comment: What does your current code look like? Are you using the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html)?

Comment: I'm trying to use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697846/python-csv-to-json
But I can't get it to work, especially with the "geo"

Comment: Can update your question with what *exactly* isn't working?

Comment: Try next time to bring some effort in your question. Don't just ask how can I do that without any own approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding, this seems to be what you want...
**Warning: Untested code....**

```
import csv, json

li = []
with open('myfile.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for location_id, name, latitude, longitude in reader:
        li.append({
           "location_id": location_id,
           "name": name,
           "latitude": latitude,
           "longitude": longitude,
           "geo": {
                "__type": "GeoPoint",
                "latitude": latitude,
                "longitude": longitude,
            }
        })
with open("outfile.geo", "w") as f:
    json.dump(li, f)
```

Comment: Thanks. How do you output the li to a file, along with the "[" and the commas between json?

Comment: let me try it out real quick

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. It seems though that two things are happening. I have ' instead of " in my output file. And even by doing the conversion float(latitude), I still get my latitude surrounded by ' ' . How can I fix this? Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks that's what I used in my answer (see below)

Answer (score 1):

I would use [geojson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geojson/). This is the format which you are dealing with.

```
>>> import geojson
>>> p = geojson.Point([0.0, 0.0])
>>> p
Point(coordinates=[0.0, 0.0])
>>> data = geojson.dumps(p)
'{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [0.0, 0.0]}'
```

Because you have no own approach yet this should be enough to generate some effort at your side.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @SchoolBoy for his guidance

Final code:

```
import csv
import json

li = []
with open('test.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:


        li.append({
           "location_id": row["location_id"],
           "name": row["name"],
           "latitude": float(row["latitude"]),
           "longitude": float(row["longitude"]),
           "geo": {
                "__type": "GeoPoint",
                "latitude": float(row["latitude"]),
                "longitude": float(row["longitude"]),
            }
        })

json.dump(li,open('file.json','w'),indent=4,sort_keys=False)
```