# Python writing a csv to a list of dictionaries with headers as keys and rows as values

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file, `test.csv`, as shown:

```
1,2,3
a,b,c
d,e,f
```

I want the above to look like a dictionary as shown:

```
{"1":"a", "2":"b", "3":"c"}
{"1":"d", "2":"e", "3":"f"}
```

where the header `1,2,3` are the keys and the rows are values.

I don't quite understand how to get this done using csv.DictReader. The above sample is just that, a sample. The actual data that I'm working with has many columns, and hence, I cannot access each row by using its index and manually putting them into a dictionary.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697846/python-csv-to-json

Comment: Thank you! This link is also a great help for my question.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Answering my own question. After trying for sometime I just now played around with it a bit more and added the for loop.

```
with open("test.csv") as f:
    records = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in records:
         print row
```

This gives my desired output of

```
{'1': 'a', '3': 'c', '2': 'b'}
{'1': 'd', '3': 'f', '2': 'e'}
```

Comment: anyone curious, add `dialect='excel-tab'` to your DictReader call and it works with tabs.

Answer (score 9):

By default first line will take as filedname in `csv.DictReader`

you can try

```
>>> a = open('/tmp/test.csv')
>>> a = csv.DictReader(open('/tmp/test.csv'), delimiter=',')
>>> [x for x in a]
[{'1': 'a', '3': 'c', '2': 'b'}, {'1': 'd', '3': 'f', '2': 'e'}]
```

This might be what your want