# Convert json to xls and after get back data to json

Tags: json, excel, csv, converters

I have a JSON example to i would like to transform to Excell file to be able to modify all fields and after that, be able to export Excell file to retrieve the new JSON file updated.

I tryed some online tool like (http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm) but the result is not good : I am able to create a csv file, but not able to convert csv file to json.

Do you know a tool with which i will be able to convert to csv / convert to json ?

**JSON example :**

```
     [
          {
            "key": "keyExample",
            "type": "typeExample",
            "ref": "refExample",
            "items": [
                {
                    "itemRef": "aaa",
                    "count": 1,
                    "desc": "aaaaaaaaa"
                },
                {
                    "itemRef": "bbb",
                    "count": 2,
                    "desc": "bbbbbbb"
                },
                {
                    "itemRef": "ccc",
                    "count": 2,
                    "desc": "ccccccc"
                }
            ]
          },
          {
            "key": "keyExample2",
            "type": "typeExample2",
            "ref": "refExample2",
            "items": [
                {
                    "itemRef": "aaa",
                    "count": 1,
                    "desc": "aaaaaaaaa"
                },
                {
                    "itemRef": "bbb",
                    "count": 2,
                    "desc": "bbbbbbb"
                },
                {
                    "itemRef": "ccc",
                    "count": 2,
                    "desc": "ccccccc"
                }
            ]
          }
     ]
```

Comment: Which language are you using to do this? If you're using Python, [does this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697846/python-csv-to-json) help?

Comment: Take another look at convertcsv.com - I've improved the conversion this year and nested JSON and nested CSV are fully supported.