# converting csv to json using python

Tags: python, json

I am converting a csv file to json array, the file gets created but the output file is empty can anyone please tell me what im doing wrong. Thanks

```
import csv  
import json  

# Open the CSV  
f = open( '/Users/br/Desktop/first100lines.csv', 'rU' )  
 reader = csv.DictReader( f, fieldnames = ("Authorized Official Last Name","Authorized Official First Name","Authorized Official Middle Name","Authorized Official Title or Position","Authorized Official Telephone Number","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_1","Provider License Number_1","Provider License Number State Code_1","Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_1","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_2","Provider License Number_2","Provider License Number State Code_2","Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_2","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_3","Provider License Number_3","Provider License Number State Code_3","Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_3","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_4","Provider License Number_4","Provider License Number State Code_4","Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_4","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_5","Provider License Number_5","Provider License Number State Code_5","Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_5","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_6","Provider License Number_6","Provider License Number State Code_6","Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_6","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_7","Provider License Number_7","Provider License Number State Code_7","Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_7","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_8","Provider License Number_8","Provider License Number State Code_8","Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_8","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_9","Provider License Number_9","Provider License Number State Code_9","Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_9","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_10","Provider License Number_10","Provider License Number State Code_10","Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_10","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_11","Provider License Number_11","Provider License Number State Code_11","Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_11","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_12","Provider License Number_12","Provider License Number State Code_12","Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_12","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_13","Provider License Number_13","Provider License Number State Code_13","Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_13","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_14","Provider License Number_14","Provider License Number State Code_14","Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_14","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_15","Provider License Number_15","Provider License Number State Code_15","Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_15","Other Provider Identifier_1","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_1","Other Provider Identifier State_1","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_1","Other Provider Identifier_2","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_2","Other Provider Identifier State_2","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_2","Other Provider Identifier_3","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_3","Other Provider Identifier State_3","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_3","Other Provider Identifier_4","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_4","Other Provider Identifier State_4","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_4","Other Provider Identifier_5","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_5","Other Provider Identifier State_5","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_5","Other Provider Identifier_6","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_6","Other Provider Identifier State_6","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_6","Other Provider Identifier_7","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_7","Other Provider Identifier State_7","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_7","Other Provider Identifier_8","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_8","Other Provider Identifier State_8","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_8","Other Provider Identifier_9","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_9","Other Provider Identifier State_9","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_9","Other Provider Identifier_10","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_10","Other Provider Identifier State_10","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_10","Other Provider Identifier_11","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_11","Other Provider Identifier State_11","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_11","Other Provider Identifier_12","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_12","Other Provider Identifier State_12","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_12","Other Provider Identifier_13","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_13","Other Provider Identifier State_13","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_13","Other Provider Identifier_14","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_14","Other Provider Identifier State_14","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_14","Other Provider Identifier_15","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_15","Other Provider Identifier State_15","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_15","Other Provider Identifier_16","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_16","Other Provider Identifier State_16","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_16","Other Provider Identifier_17","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_17","Other Provider Identifier State_17","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_17","Other Provider Identifier_18","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_18","Other Provider Identifier State_18","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_18","Other Provider Identifier_19","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_19","Other Provider Identifier State_19","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_19","Other Provider Identifier_20","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_20","Other Provider Identifier State_20","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_20","Other Provider Identifier_21","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_21","Other Provider Identifier State_21","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_21","Other Provider Identifier_22","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_22","Other Provider Identifier State_22","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_22","Other Provider Identifier_23","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_23","Other Provider Identifier State_23","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_23","Other Provider Identifier_24","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_24","Other Provider Identifier State_24","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_24","Other Provider Identifier_25","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_25","Other Provider Identifier State_25","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_25","Other Provider Identifier_26","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_26","Other Provider Identifier State_26","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_26","Other Provider Identifier_27","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_27","Other Provider Identifier State_27","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_27","Other Provider Identifier_28","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_28","Other Provider Identifier State_28","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_28","Other Provider Identifier_29","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_29","Other Provider Identifier State_29","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_29","Other Provider Identifier_30","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_30","Other Provider Identifier State_30","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_30","Other Provider Identifier_31","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_31","Other Provider Identifier State_31","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_31","Other Provider Identifier_32","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_32","Other Provider Identifier State_32","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_32","Other Provider Identifier_33","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_33","Other Provider Identifier State_33","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_33","Other Provider Identifier_34","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_34","Other Provider Identifier State_34","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_34","Other Provider Identifier_35","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_35","Other Provider Identifier State_35","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_35","Other Provider Identifier_36","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_36","Other Provider Identifier State_36","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_36","Other Provider Identifier_37","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_37","Other Provider Identifier State_37","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_37","Other Provider Identifier_38","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_38","Other Provider Identifier State_38","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_38","Other Provider Identifier_39","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_39","Other Provider Identifier State_39","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_39","Other Provider Identifier_40","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_40","Other Provider Identifier State_40","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_40","Other Provider Identifier_41","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_41","Other Provider Identifier State_41","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_41","Other Provider Identifier_42","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_42","Other Provider Identifier State_42","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_42","Other Provider Identifier_43","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_43","Other Provider Identifier State_43","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_43","Other Provider Identifier_44","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_44","Other Provider Identifier State_44","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_44","Other Provider Identifier_45","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_45","Other Provider Identifier State_45","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_45","Other Provider Identifier_46","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_46","Other Provider Identifier State_46","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_46","Other Provider Identifier_47","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_47","Other Provider Identifier State_47","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_47","Other Provider Identifier_48","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_48","Other Provider Identifier State_48","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_48","Other Provider Identifier_49","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_49","Other Provider Identifier State_49","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_49","Other Provider Identifier_50","Other Provider Identifier Type Code_50","Other Provider Identifier State_50","Other Provider Identifier Issuer_50","Is Sole Proprietor","Is Organization Subpart","Parent Organization LBN","Parent Organization TIN","Authorized Official Name Prefix Text","Authorized Official Name Suffix Text","Authorized Official Credential Text","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_1","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_2","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_3","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_4","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_5","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_6","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_7","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_8","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_9","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_10","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_11","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_12","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_13","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_14","Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_15" ))  
out = json.dumps( [ row for row in reader ] )  
print "JSON parsed!"  
f = open( '/Users/br/Desktop/parsed.json', 'w')  
f.write(out)  
print "JSON saved!"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697846/python-csv-to-json
http://jaranto.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/transform-csv-file-to-json-file-with.html
http://kailaspatil.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/python-script-to-convert-json-file-into.html
http://ask.schoolofdata.org/question/91/what-is-the-best-tool-to-convert-a-csv-file-to-a-json/

I am sure you can figure it out :)

Comment: ive tried doing it different ways yet i get an empty document but the other way i got a traceback for convert(sys.argv[1:]) what could i possibly be missing

Comment: You never close the file, and so I don't think it will be written to disk

Answer (score 1):

Using standard libraries

**data.csv**

```
field1,field2,field3
1,test,3
4,5,sample
```

**Python**

```
import csv, json

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csvdata:
    next(csvdata, None) # skip the headers
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvdata,fieldnames=['field1', 'field2','field3'])
    json.dump([row for row in reader], open('output.json', 'w+'))
```

**output.json**

```
[{
    "field2": "test",
    "field3": "3",
    "field1": "1"
}, {
    "field2": "5",
    "field3": "sample",
    "field1": "4"
}]
```

Comment: the output document is still empty.

Comment: Well, works for me, so you're doing something wrong.

Comment: i have both string and int does that change anything?

Comment: CSV has no concept of int, so everything is converted to a string. See edits

Comment: idk what is wrong, i did a csvkit install and did csvjson data.csv > data.json to see if i can atleast get the whole document to convert, it just gives me the result

Comment: how can i break a large json document into one  with fewer attributes?

Comment: I don't know what csvkit is... Like I said, this code works. And to get fewer attributes, make fewer columns... Not sure what you're asking there

Comment: i made some changes to it and it works now Thank you! But instead of getting all the data into 1 array how would i make every coloumn in to an arrray?

Comment: You'd have to transpose the data... Do you want me to make that edit?

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using other packages such as [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), it can be done with 3 lines.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.txt')

df.to_json('data.json')
```

Printout of `df` (test.txt):

```
       c1    c2    c3    c4
0    this    is  line     1
1    this  will    be     2
2       3  does  also  work
3  better     4  like  this
```

Printout of `data.json` (prettified):

```
{  
   "c1":{  
      "0":"this",
      "1":"this",
      "2":"3",
      "3":"better"
   },
   "c2":{  
      "0":"is",
      "1":"will",
      "2":"does",
      "3":"4"
   },
   "c3":{  
      "0":"line",
      "1":"be",
      "2":"also",
      "3":"like"
   },
   "c4":{  
      "0":"1",
      "1":"2",
      "2":"work",
      "3":"this"
   }
}
```

Comment: what is that to_json?

Comment: this solution has a flaw. In column **c1** row **2** the value could be a numeric value but after conversion to **json** it is now a string.

Answer (score 0):

with [tablib](http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/latest/) you can do:

```
# csv with tab as sep
imported_data = Dataset().load(open('/Users/br/Desktop/first100lines.csv').read())
# export as json
# (http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/latest/tutorial/#exporting-data)
imported_data.json
```

Comment: im going to run this as a recurring cronjob on an amazon ec2 instsance, im assuming it wouldnt work on that instance?

Comment: There is no reason. You can install the package via pip or download it in a folder PYTHONPATH accessible. :)

Comment: i tried your approach but the document is still empty

Comment: what's mean "the document" ?