# CSV string to JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, file, csv

Im retrieving a report from the google adwords api as string which contains csv (using downloadReportAsString). I want to convert this to JSON, only all
the converters expect a csv file type but mine is currently a string.
How do I get the string to csv file? I read something about stringIO.
I'm using python 3

Comment: Unclear what format of JSON you want. Please give example

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By using `io.StringIO` you can use the normal csv readers and then dump it out to json.

```
>>> import csv, io, json
>>> 
>>> string = """a,b,c
... 1,2,3
... 4,5,6
... """
>>> 
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(string))
>>> 
>>> json_data = json.dumps(list(reader))
>>> json_data
'[{"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3"}, {"a": "4", "b": "5", "c": "6"}]'
```

Comment: I actually didn't take it right from there. I guess abc123 is common test data. Thanks for linking though! That answer also has a bit better explanation.

Comment: Also: [CSV to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697846/python-csv-to-json)

Comment: json_data is a string. How can be obtained as a Python dictionary?