# Convert CSV with a parent column to a herarchical json /s in python

Tags: python, json, csv, d3.js

I have CSV file (`data.csv`) which contains a column with its parent id. Based on this file, I would like to create one or many `json` files which contain the root and all its children. An example for a CSV file with one root only:

```
BrandID,Name,ParentBrandID
1,Brand,
2,Normal Brand,1
3,Bad Brand,1
4,Best Brand,1
5,Cleaner,4
6,Fat Remover,4
7,Others,1
8,Kitchen,7
```

And I need to convert that file to a `json` format that looks like this:

```
    {
        "name":"Brand",
        "children":[
            {
                "name":"Normal Brand"
            },
            {
                "name":"Bad Brand"
            },
            {
                "name":"Best Brand",
                "children":[
                    {
                        "name":"Cleaner"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"Fat Remover"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name":"Others",
                "children":[
                    {
                        "name":"Kitchen"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Is there an straight forward way to do this?

If it helps for anything, I need this to use as an entry for `d3` libraries.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide the code you have written and an explanation of how it's failing then someone may be able to assist. Have a look at the Asking session in the Help pages: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python CSV to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697846/python-csv-to-json)

Comment: I haven't written any particular code to solve this. The question is if there's any method that does this already? Otherwise I can develop my own converter.