# Ensure unique values within sub elements of a json element while converting from csv

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm using the answer here to convert my csv to json in python .

[How to convert CSV file to multiline JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697846/how-to-convert-csv-file-to-multiline-json)

Although each json field is unique . I'm not sure how to ensure how each sub json field has a list of unique elements.

Ex:

```
fieldnames = ("domains","ip_address")
reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames)
for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
     jsonfile.write('\n')
```

Basically I want to ensure all the items in the ip_address list are unique. 
In case of the list shown below :

```
{"ip_address":"x,y,x"}
```

It should be :

```
{"ip_address":"x,y"}
```

I know how to obtain unique values from a list. I want to know how to access this list while performing the json dump.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and describe how it failed?

Comment: provide an example with desired output

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', ...]

unique_list = []
for word in my_list:
    if word not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(word)
```

Hope it helps
THanks