# Transpose CSV to JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have a csv similar to below and wanted transpose as JSON

Input:

[image]

Output I expect to get:

```
{
"C1" :[ {"header2" : "name1", "header 3" : "address 1"}, {"header2" : "name3", "header 3" : "address 3"}],
"C2" : [ {"header2" : "name2", "header 3" : "address 2"}]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Based on some comments, some people are just `pandas` haters. But I like to use the tool that allows me to solve the problem in the easiest manner possible, and with the fewest lines of code.

  - In this case, without a doubt, that's `pandas`
  - An added benefit of using `pandas`, is the data can easily be clean, analyzed , and visualized, if needed.
  - Solutions at [How to convert CSV file to multiline JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697846/how-to-convert-csv-file-to-multiline-json) offer some basics, but won't help transform the csv into the required shape.
- Because of the expected output of the `JSON` file, this is a non-trivial question, which requires reshaping/grouping the data in the csv and is easily accomplished with [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby).

  - `groupby` `'h1'` since the column values will be the `dict` outer keys
  - `groupby` returns a `DataFrameGroupBy` object that can be split into, `i`, the value used to create the group (`'c1'` and `'c2'` in this case) and the associated dataframe group, `g`.

    - Use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html#pandas-dataframe-to-dict) to convert the dataframe into a list of dictionaries.

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

# read the file
df = pd.DataFrame('test.csv')

# display(df)
   h1  h2  h3
0  c1  n1  a1
1  c2  n2  a2
2  c1  n3  a3

# groupby and create dict
data_dict = dict()
for i, g in df.groupby('h1'):
    data_dict[i] = g.drop(columns=['h1']).to_dict(orient='records')

# print(data_dict)
{'c1': [{'h2': 'n1', 'h3': 'a1'}, {'h2': 'n3', 'h3': 'a3'}],
 'c2': [{'h2': 'n2', 'h3': 'a2'}]}

# save data_dict to a file as a JSON
with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(data_dict, fp)
```

### JSON file

```
{
    "c1": [{
            "h2": "n1",
            "h3": "a1"
        }, {
            "h2": "n3",
            "h3": "a3"
        }
    ],
    "c2": [{
            "h2": "n2",
            "h3": "a2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm [far from a Pandas hater](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a1426065%20pandas), I just (mistakenly) though it would be just as easy and less resource-intensive to use the `csv` and `json` modules directly. However, I didn't take into account the data munging that had to take place to give the results the OP was after. Have an upvote.