# Read file and convert to JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have file which contains the data in comma separated and i want final output to be json data. I tried below but wanted to know is there any better way to implement this?

data.txt

```
1,002, name, address
2,003, name_1, address_2
3,004, name_2, address_3
```

I want final output like below

```
{
"Id": "1",
"identifier": "002",
"mye": "name",
"add": "address"
}
{
"Id": "2",
"identifier": "003",
"mye": "name_2",
"add": "address_2"
}
and so on...
```

here is code which i am trying

```
list = []

with open('data.txt') as reader:
     for line in reader:
         list.append(line.split(','))
          
print(list)
```

above just return the list but i need to convert json key value pair defined in above

Comment: What have you tried wrt the conversion part? Did you use a `dict`?

Comment: Are you aware of the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module?

Comment: @quamrana can you please share few example. very new to Python

Comment: your `.txt` is actually a CSV file. So the question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697846/how-to-convert-csv-file-to-multiline-json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desired result isn't actually JSON.  It's just a series of dict structures.  What *I think* you want is a list of dictionaries.  Try this:

```py
fields = ["Id", "identifier", "mye", "add"]
my_json = []

with open('data.txt') as reader:
     for line in reader:
         vals = line.rstrip().split(',')
         my_json.append({fields[vals.index(val)]: val for val in vals})
print(my_json)
```

Comment: thanks for example, i see each end of line appended with '\n' how to remove in your loop?

Comment: Just add an `rstrip()` between `line` and `split(',')`.  Answer edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
import json

dataList = []

with open('data.txt') as reader:
    # split lines in a way that strips unnecessary whitespace and newlines
    for line in reader.read().replace(' ', '').split('\n'):
        lineData = line.split(',')
        dataList.append({
            "Id":           lineData[0],
            "identifier":   lineData[1],
            "mye":          lineData[2],
            "add":          lineData[3]
        })
out_json = json.dumps(dataList)
print(out_json)
```

Note that you can change this line:

```
out_json = json.dumps(dataList)
```

to

```
out_json = json.dumps(dataList, indent=4)
```

and change the indent value to format the json output.

And you can write it to a file if you want to:

```
open("out.json", "w+").write(out_json)
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension to one of the suggestion, but you can consider `zip` instead of list comprehension

```
import json
my_json = []
dict_header=["Id","identifier","mye","add"]
with open('data.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        my_json.append(dict ( zip ( dict_header, line.split('\n')[0].split(',')) ))

out_file = open("test1.json", "w")
json.dump(my_json, out_file, indent = 4, sort_keys = False)
out_file.close()
```

This of course assuming you save the from excel to text(Tab delimnited) in excel

```
1   2   name    address
2   3   name_1  address_2
3   4   name_2  address_3
```

Comment: see edit @quamrana. This assuming OP get the `txt` from excel save as .tab delimited`

Comment: Why make that assumption? Why not take what the OP has supplied in 'data.txt'?

Comment: OP did not  share this information hence the assumption

Comment: In what way did the OP not share this information? Its been there from the original post.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest using pandas library, it can't get any easier.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.txt", header=None)

df.columns = ["Id","identifier", "mye","add"]

df.to_json("output.json")
```