# Is there a way to put JSON data to django models?

Tags: python, django

So what I want to do here is that take a CSV file as input from an HTML form, then convert the CSV to JSON and put the JSON values into a Django model.

I looked on the web, but the answers were not convincing enough, and they were also not what I wanted.

Is there a way to do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well its possible by `json` module of python, there are two methods `json.dumps()` and `json.loads()`.

Comment: Okay, I will look into it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert CSV data to JSON with `csv` and `json` modules as explained in this [Stack Overflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697846/how-to-convert-csv-file-to-multiline-json)


*EDIT*

```py
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('file.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('file.json', 'w')

fieldnames = ("FirstName","LastName","IDNumber","Message")
reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames)
for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

Then, you can store json data in a Django model thank to [django-jsonfield][2]. You can have a look at mdegis answer in this [Stack Overflow discussion][3] 


*EDIT*

```py
from django.db import models
import jsonfield

class MyModel(models.Model):
    the_json = jsonfield.JSONField()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For a variety of reasons, [link-only answers are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/248627). Please edit your answer and include the main points directly in your question. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give you the logic. I didn't test the code. *You may need to clear views.py.*

**Before we started in the command line:**

```
pip install pandas
```

**in HTML**:

`<input type="file" accept=".csv" />`

**in views.py**

```
import pandas as pd

def form_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        df = pd.read_csv (request.POST.get('csv'))
        df.to_json (turned_json)
        my_obj = CsvModel.objects.create(csv_file=turned_json)
        my_obj.save()
return render(request, 'form.html')
```

**in models.py**

```
class CsvModel(models.Model):
    csv_file = models.FileField()
```